# Почему утилита protoc не видит с++ плагин?(grpc)

Tags: c++, grpc

Я пытаюсь скомпилировать .proto файл командами

```
protoc --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_cpp_plugin` test.proto
protoc --cpp_out=. test.proto
```

Но при выполнении первой команды возникает ошибка

> : program not found or is not executable Please specify a program
> using absolute path or make sure the program is available in your PATH
> system variable
> --grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.

Судя по всему, я неправильно указываю плагин, или что то в этом духе. как пример брал команду по windiws, там в качестве плагина предается grpc_cpp_plugin.exe, запись `which grpc_cpp_plugin` я взял из официальной документации.
Что нужно передать в качестве плагина, что команда сработала ?

утилиту ptotoc я установил со snap пакетов ubunu, так же из репозитория я скачал пакет  libgrpc-dev

Comment: Попробуйте `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`grpc_cpp_plugin` (без which). Еще просто запустите `grpc_cpp_plugin`, и посмотрите запустится или нет.

Answer (score 0):

Указано что исполняемый файл (то есть программу которая генерирует код исходя из .proto файла) "protoc-gen-grpc" не может найти в пути $PATH. Для этого нужно:

`Пути в примерах и у тебя могут отличаться.`

1. Разобраться есть ли эта программа и узнать её расположение.

   ```
   $ whereis protoc-gen-grpc
   /opt/homebrew/bin/protoc-gen-grpc
   ```
2. Проверить есть ли в переменной $PATH путь к `/opt/homebrew/bin`

   ```
   $ echo $PATH
   /opt/homebrew/sbin
   ```
3. Добавить в переменную путь

   ```
   $ export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin
   ```